# How to create Google Satellite tiles in a plugin for new projects

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am currently developing a plugin that is designed to insert information into a database, as well as fetch styles and data for insertion into new projects. As a part of this plugin's functionalities, I am trying to implement the creation of Google Satellite tiles from plugin *QuickMapServices*.

Despite my efforts in researching this, I am unable to find a suitable solution or approach to this problem. Most of the resources I find pertain to the QGIS Plugin menu / interface, which is not what I intend to use.

Could anyone provide guidance or point me in the right direction? Are there any alternative ways to create these Google Satellite tiles without using the standard way, by selecting in it's interface?

Comment: Just add as an XYZ tile layer URL `https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`